# Backbone Routers & Page Refresh

Tags: backbone.js

I have two routers, each with one route. The first router, lets call it the page router, handles the route: `""` by drawing the page furniture (header, footer, etc.). The second router, the module router, deals with a hash route, `":program/config"` by showing in the middle of the page the configuration for the chosen program.

The user starts the app by going to the home page: `http://host/service/home.html`. This causes the page router to draw the home page. The user chooses one of the program configs from the menu and the url changes to: `http://host/service/home.html#ABC/config`. This causes the module router to display the correct module.

The issue is that when the page refreshes, only the module router is invoked. The page correctly renders the module content, but the menu is gone -- the page router isn't invoked.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your page router have a route with value `""` which doesn't exist when you have a url with `abc/config`. It would be better if you remove the page router and leave only the module router.

Try doing your application to execute whatever the page router is doing `onLoad` time and leave only one router.

Creating a header and footer that are all the same on every page isn't job for a router.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would it not matter that the abc/config is an anchor, not part of the url proper? On your last point: the header/footer in my app are driven through backbone, and are complex objects in their own right that need resources configured in the router -- it wouldn't be right to configure my entire app in the page load, especially as some of the config is done in the sub-router.

Comment: It seems like that's the way to do this sort of thing in Backbone: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/02/06/3-stages-of-a-backbone-applications-startup/ From what I can understand - you need to encapsulate the startup logic (header/footer rendering with the data fetching they need) in some kind of module, depend on that module in your main.js (if you're using require.js or equivalent like $ doc load event) and start up there. Then if there's different init for diff routes, add those to ure module and depend on it and use specific init methods for that route.